# Selenium WebDriver can't load profile

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I try firing up Firefox using Selenium WebDriver and get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-9e1140c380e1> in <module>()
----> 1 t = tweepi.Tweepi(username, 0, profile_name)

/home/ubuntu/twitter/tweepi.pyc in __init__(self, username, threadid, profilename)
     22             profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profilename)
     23             self.logger.debug('launching firefox')
---> 24             self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile)
     25         else:
     26             self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.pyc in __init__(self, firefox_profile, firefox_binary, timeout, capabilities, proxy)
     57         RemoteWebDriver.__init__(self,
     58             command_executor=ExtensionConnection("127.0.0.1", self.profile,
---> 59             self.binary, timeout),
     60             desired_capabilities=capabilities,
     61             keep_alive=True)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.pyc in __init__(self, host, firefox_profile, firefox_binary, timeout)
     45         self.profile.add_extension()
     46 
---> 47         self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
     48         _URL = "http://%s:%d/hub" % (HOST, PORT)
     49         RemoteConnection.__init__(

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.pyc in launch_browser(self, profile)
     62 
     63         self._start_from_profile_path(self.profile.path)
---> 64         self._wait_until_connectable()
     65 
     66     def kill(self):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.pyc in _wait_until_connectable(self)
    106                 raise WebDriverException("Can't load the profile. Profile "
    107                       "Dir: %s Firefox output: %s" % (
--> 108                           self.profile.path, self._get_firefox_output()))
    109             count += 1
    110             time.sleep(1)

WebDriverException: Message: "Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: /tmp/tmp4nBIo5/webdriver-py-profilecopy Firefox output: None"
```

Now, every other similar thread I found here on stackoverflow says the solution is to update selenium by using the command

> pip install -U selenium

This fixed the problem on my local computer, but the problem persists on my remote computer on AWS. These two computers have the same Firefox version, both have selenium up-to-date and they even have the exact same profile folder on ~/.mozilla/firefox.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I can start Firefox without the profile. That is, doing

```
w = webdriver.Firefox()
```

works, whereas doing

```
profile_name = '/home/ubuntu/.mozilla/firefox/amozqob6.profile6'
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile_name)
w = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

gets the above error message.

EDIT2:

Running the Firefox executable directly works:

```
firefox -profile ~/.mozilla/firefox/amozqob6.profile6
```

Comment: Are you able to start a Selenium session without a custom profile?  Try just starting a vanilla Firefox Webdriver instance on the remote.

Comment: @SilasRay Indeed, it works. I updated the question. Suggestions?

Comment: I don't know that much about the internals of Firefox profiles, but as a first stab, did you by chance create the profile you are using on a different OS than is on your AWS instance?  I don't know if FF profiles are portable across OSes.

Comment: @SilasRay I created it on local Ubuntu 12 32-bit, whereas remote is 16-bit. However, it should work because I've done it before. I've recently had to upgrade Firefox from 30 to 32 (for other reasons) and was trying to get everything working again, and last time what I did was create profile on local and copy to remote.

Comment: Remote is 16 bit?  You sure about that?  Maybe you mean 64?

Comment: @SilasRay Sorry, yeah. One is 32 the other one is 64.

Comment: Well, go at it from the other direction then.  See if you can launch Firefox from the terminal on the remote using the -profile flag to provide the profile path to your custom profile.  If it works, it's some funky thing with Python or Selenium, and if not, then maybe it will give you a more useful error from Firefox to point you at what's wrong with the profile.

Comment: @SilasRay I just tried, and it does work, which like you said means the problem is with Python or Selenium. This isn't surprising though, because like I said, on my local just upgrading selenium solved the problem. I'm gonna try a remote 64-bit now. This will take a while.

Comment: @SilasRay I just installed everything in a 32-bit instance, like local, and I'm still getting the same error. Assuming that isn't a really really obscure bug with the operating system (because upgrading selenium solved the issue in local), what else do you suggest?

Comment: I'd try building another profile.  After that, maybe uninstall Selenium/Python/Firefox.  It's kind of a hard problem to diagnose, especially without access to the boxes and lots of research online.

Answer (score 3):

helped me to specify an explicit path to the binary file firefox

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
binary = FirefoxBinary("/home/teddy/firefox/firefox")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```