# Python test using selenium cannot perform simple test

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to learn about Selenium but I am not able to get even a simple program to test. Selenium webdriver seems to not be cooperating with Firefox and I am very frustrated, so I come to Stack Overflow for help.

For background, I use Python, can install with pip, and know command line.
I am on windows 10, firefox 48, and selenium webdriver 3 with python 3.5.2

Whenever I run the selenium test, (it opens a Firefox windows and the selenium website)

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.seleniumhq.org')
```

I always get an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: C:\ ... \AppData\Local\Temp\tmp68m5rtwt If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details
```

It also opens a firefox window and has the link of `about:blank&utm_content=firstrun`(not a valid url)

I have looked across the internet for a similar situation, but nothing really close. I also tried many tutorials and made sure that I installed selenium the right way. I noticed that firefox was recently updated, but I am not sure if this has any effect.

I would appreciate any help for this, and instructions for what I should do.

Comment: For some reason it's failing to load / create a profile. Could be permissions, integrity errors, who knows. Try the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126588/selenium-webdriver-cant-load-profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox 48+ doesn't support `webdriver.Firefox()`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
caps["marionette"] = True
caps["binary"] = "path/to/your/firefox"

browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps)
browser.get('http://www.seleniumhq.org')
```

This is what I was trying
1. download `geckodriver`.https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases. `v.0.10.0`is for `selenium 3(beta)`.
2. add PATH your geckodriver.
4. rename it to  `wires`
5. restart shell
6. check the version
`$ wires --version`
7. and run above the code.